# Heroku Cedar-14 and libjpeg.so.62

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

After upgrading a production application on Heroku to cedar-14, I am running into issues with [carrierwave-video-thumbnailer](https://github.com/evrone/carrierwave-video-thumbnailer).  In particular, I get the error:

```
ffmpegthumbnailer: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After looking into this, I found that other people are having issues with libjpeg after upgrading to cedar-14 (for other gems besides ffmpegthumbnailer)

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to fix this?, or otherwise
2. How can I revert back to cedar-10?

(I tried heroku stack:set cedar-10 but get the error `resource not found`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a limited time left on cedar-10, so you'd do well to try to fix the issue. However, if you need to revert it temporarily, read on.

`heroku stack:set cedar` doesn't seem to be working anymore, probably because it is a ticking time bomb.

To rollback, you can use the `heroku rollback` functionality.

1. First, get the version number of the most recent release before you upgraded.

   `heroku releases`
2. Then, do:

   `heroku rollback v65`

   (using the version you identified from the previous step instead of v65)

Good luck!

Comment: Cedar 10 is only going to be supported till november perhaps